# How do I insert a variable image file in a rmarkdown pdf

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

The problem is simple - How do I insert a variable filename into an rmarkdown PDF?  I want to do this:

```
---
FNL = "image.png"
---

![Some Text](params$FNL)
```

only I need to pass in the value for FNL when calling rmarkdown::render

The purpose is to give the image a unique ID so that users get images marked for their session.

Anyone able to help with this?

Comment: Just saw an error, should be (%s) not %s, but the change does not make any difference.  Now I get the picture label correctly displayed, by still no picture.

Comment: Well `paste0` works just fine. I just changed the solution since `sprintf` is a little more elegant and improves readability due to fewer quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use inline R evaluation (works for both HTML and PDF output):

```
---
title: "Example"
author: "Martin"
date: "March, 11 2017"
output: html_document
params:
  img: NULL
---

`r sprintf("![A good boy](%s)", params$img)`
```

Then you can render the document with the image file by calling
 `rmarkdown::render("MyDocument.Rmd", params = list(img = "unnamed.png"))`.

[image]

Comment: See notes above.  I tried your example directly and discovered that the rmd was looking for the working directory, when I ran the rmd from that working directory It works just fine!

Comment: But my app still will not work - I cannot figure out where the pdf is expecting the image to be located

Comment: You can always use raw Latex to include graphics and use the placement options (see google):`sprintf("\\includegraphics[options]{%s}", params$img)`

Comment: That does not help, thanks.  It appears that the rmd is looking for the file somewhere, but not in the workind directory or in the temp folder where several .rmd's are assembled into the pdf report.  I cannot figure out where it is looking for the file.  Even if I hard code an existing file name, it cannot find it in either place.  I will close out this question and try to write a new one for this specific problem