# inserting image using parameters in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

My image names are the same as the unique ids. I need to insert the image names using the params to batch create 100 files at one go. I am unable to get the image part work. please let me know how do I pass file names for image through params.

---

```
title: Title
subtitle: Subtitle
output: pdf_document
params: 
  Unique_ID : '011'
---

![](params$Unique_ID.png)
```

Comment: You could use an inline chunk, i.e. try `\`r sprintf("![](%s.png)", params$Unique_ID)\``. See [How do I insert a variable image file in a rmarkdown pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49203660/how-do-i-insert-a-variable-image-file-in-a-rmarkdown-pdf)